# Product of hypergeometric functions/Jacobi Polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics, special-functions

Are there any theorems related to the product of Jacobi/Legendre Polynomials and/or Hypergeometric functions? Specifically, I'm interested in the product of ${}_{2}F_{1}[-n,-n+1;2;x]$ and ${}_{2}F_{1}[-n-1,-n+3;2;x]$ hoping to obtain it in some form ${}_{p}F_{q}$.

I've found some stuff in Bailey (1928,1935), but it has solutions only for some special cases. I've also obtained the coefficient of the $k$th term $\frac{x^k}{k!}$. I get (in case I didn't make any mistakes)

$\sum_{m=0}^{k} \binom{k}{m} \binom{n}{m}\binom{n-1}{m}\binom{n+1}{k-m}\binom{n-3}{k-m} \frac{m!\,(k-m)!}{(m+1)(k-m+1)}$, but I don't quite see what to do next.

Comment: Have you tried http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/?

Comment: See http://www.mathkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/symbolic-math/936/2F1-2F1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, there is no general formula of the type you wanted
but a whole bunch of the formulae expressing the product of
two $_2F_1$ by hypergeometric (or nearly hypergeometric) means.
They are known as Orr-type theorems and can be found in
Slater's book "Generalized hypergeometric functions", Section 2.5
(there are some instances in Bailey's "Generalized hypergeometric series"
as well). A famous example of this type is Clausen's identity
$$
{}_2F_1(a,b;a+b+\tfrac12\mid z)^2
={}_3F_2(2a,2b,a+b;2a+2b,a+b+\tfrac12\mid z).
$$
In addition, you can use the contiguous relations
[Slater, Section 1.4] which allow one to produce linear 
relations between any three functions of the form
${}_2F_1(a+n,b+m;c+k\mid z)$ where $n,m,k\in\mathbb Z$,
as well as the transformation [Slater, Section 1.7.1]
$$
{}_2F_1(a,b;c\mid z)
=(1-z)^{-a}{}_2F_1\biggl(a,c-b;c\Bigm|\frac{z}{z-1}\biggr).
$$

I do not see however that something spectacular happens for
your particular product. In fact, the algorithm described
in the (already mentioned) book "$A=B$" decides whether the
expression $a_k$ given by
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k
:={}_2F_1(-n,-n+1;2\mid z){}_2F_1(-n-1,-n+3;2\mid z)
$$
(so that each $a_k$ is a single hypergeometric sum) can be
represented as a sum of *finite* rational terms. If this is
the case (which I really doubt), then you will have your wanted
product as a finite sum of hypergeometric functions; if not,
then this is the *proof* that you have no expression of this type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to look at the recurrence relation satisfied by the product of Jacobi polynomials?
(For example, maple/gfun finds product recurrences, but a list of related packages is on the site http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~slc/divers/software.html of the Seminaire Lotharingien de Combinatoire.)

In general, this will not be a single sum, but a lot of things can be done just by using the recurrence relation instead of a sum representation and there is the Petkovsek algorithm to check if a nice closed-form solution exists.

(A good reference is the book A=B by Petkovsek, Wilf and Zeilberger http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/Downld.html)

(BTW I don't think that your expression for the coefficient is correct but I may have copied it incorrectly.)