# Non-standard addition theorem for Legendre function of the first kind

Tags: special-functions, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

There is known [link text](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%252FANZ%252FANZ37_02%252FS0334270000007670a.pdf&code=be0b92ec2c3bdb1cef0a6e06d5ccf9fa) addition theorem for the Legendre functions of the first kind $P_{\nu}^m(x)$, which establishes the connection between $P_{\nu}^m(x)P_{\nu}^{m}(y)$ and $P_{\nu}(F(x,y))$ for some concrete function $F(x,y)$ (which itself deals with the spherical distance, but let's not think about it for a moment). But what about addition theorem, in which $\mu$ does vary, while $x$ is fixed? I mean, say for $m=0$, is there any expression of $P_{\nu}(x)P_{\mu}(x)$ via $P_{f(\nu,\mu)}(g(x))$ for some functions $f$, $g$?

Comment: Dear Fedor Petrov, I have added the classical analysis tag, thinking it could be useful.

Comment: Fedor, the Legendre functions are special instances of the $_2F_1$ hypergeometric functions, so there products would normally satisfy the differential equations of order 3 (at least!), hence could hardly be given as another LF. See also my answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58374/product-of-hypergeometric-functions-jacobi-polynomials/69392#69392 . I'd like to point out that the link in your Q is dead, and I am interested to see what kind of addition formula is meant there.

Comment: ops, sorry, hope that this one works:
http://journals.cambridge.org/article_S0334270000007670



Comment: Such formulas are called "linearization formula" for product of polynomials, for example see formula $(5.9)$ in this article [LINEARIZATION OF PRODUCTS OF JACOBI POLYNOMIALS](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjz_q-srObXAhVQkeAKHX3RDPEQFghBMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mscand.dk%2Farticle%2Fdownload%2F10527%2F8548&usg=AOvVaw3jGVu0fg9F5a08WELZ2j8c) by E.A. Hylleraas.